# How to run multiple node HTTP server apps at different paths? (without express or alike)

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a solution that allows me to create different `node` apps for each of the major concerns that a server project should deal with (aka. `frontend` and `backend`).
Each of the apps should only handle requests coming on paths designated to it, completely ignoring requests on the other paths. Ideally, requests coming on paths not designated for an app, should never reach that app at all. More exactly:

- a dedicated `backend` only app handling all requests coming to `https://<some-domain.abc>/api`.
  This is the only path that should bother this app.
- a `frontend` only app handling all other paths, except the `/api` one

The frontend and backend apps could either run on the same physical server, or they could run on completely different physical servers. They should be completely independent, unaware of each other, except for the API interface.
It is possible that later on some other apps will be added to handle requests coming on other paths, but none is planned right now (maybe `/graphiql` for debugging graphql).

I know this question has come up multiple times in the past, but the answers I have found always reference some http ready-made server package (`express` comes up in 99% of cases). I do not want to use such packages, I am using the bare node `http`/`https`/`http/2` packages and building up the stack on my own.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a http proxy using only nodejs?

Comment: @Bergi I am looking for any alternatives, not just nginx

Answer (score 3):

A reverse proxy (Nginx/Apache) would help you accomplish this.